# Why does this exception occur: "java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key MQJE001b"?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have installed IBM MQ 7.5.0.5 client and adding ALL the jars under C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib to the classpath of my Java application. But when writing to the queue using my Java program I get following exception:

```
 java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key MQJE001b
     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(Unknown Source)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQException.getMessage(MQException.java:1638)
     at com.ibm.mq.ReasonCodeInfo.getResourceException(ReasonCodeInfo.java:191)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:600)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:630)
     at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:107)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:205)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:911)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:799)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:750)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:157)
     at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:681)
```

The exception occurs when executing following statement:

```
MQQueueManager manager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
```

I checked all the points mentioned [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/186176/why-does-this-error-occur-exception-in-thread-main.html), but didn't get any clue yet.

Can anyone help please? What am I missing here? I use JDK7u79.

Comment: Re: "added all the jars"  Just curious, why didn't you set up the `CLASSPATH` according to IBM's instructions?  According to the manual you need only a couple jars so if you add them to the `CLASSPATH` explicitly it changes the load order and inheritence.  See: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031560_.htm

Comment: @T.Rob Yes, thanks for that. I have included minimal set of jars now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I figured out the reason now. I was using the old mqji.properties file. The new file is already there in com.ibm.mq.jar, but was being ignored as old file was still available in my classpath. Now it works fine.